# Jquery - Tooltip not working

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I found a tutorial on a tooltip and I tried to copy it without looking at it. After I did that I found some differences in my code and the tutorial. So I fixed it, but still it doesn't show up.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/8RTqC/

Nevermind, I found the problem.

Changed

```
  tip = $(this).find('.tooltip');
```

for

```
  tip = $('.tooltip');
```

and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is wrong:

```
tip = $(this).find('.tooltip');
```

This looks for an element with class 'tooltip' within your anchor.  Just use:

```
var tip = $('.tooltip');
```

Comment: This would break down for more than one tooltip on the page.

Comment: That is right. I was just pointing out the reason his script didn't work was due to the bad selector.  As far as supporting multiple tooltips, there are many approaches (including your answer -- which would break if your tooltip wasn't next to your trigger).  You could enforce a classname based association, use data(), or markup-based relationships.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it per link, you need to replace this:

```
$(this).find('.tooltip')
```

With a method that looks for the tooltip a a sibling, instead of *inside* the `<a>`, like this:

```
$(this).next('.tooltip')
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/8RTqC/2/).

Comment: that's pretty much what I did, but the box doesn't follow the mouse if I move it through the link.

Comment: @Baruch - because you're using the `mouseover` event, you need the `mousemove` event if you want it to update, like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/8RTqC/3/

Comment: Oh!! that's why. Thanks Nick.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off not reinventing the wheel.  Try this:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html